# "NSManagedObjectContext+MagicalThreading.h" file not Foundというエラーで困っています。

Tags: swift

MagicalRecordに関しての質問となります。

下記の手順でMagicalRecordの設定を行い、下記のエラーが生じました。
どう対処して良いのか解決中ですが、何か間違いや、解決策をご存知でしたらお教えいただければ幸いです。

1 XcodeProjectの生成

2 podファイルの設定

```
//pod init
//add in MagicalRecord + AFNetworking


// Objective-C
#import <MagicalRecord/MagicalRecord.h>

//追加する予定の外部ファイル
#import <AFNetworking.h>
#import <UIImageView+AFNetworking.h>
#import <AFNetworkActivityLogger.h>

//pod install
```

3 TodoApp-Bridging-Header.hファイルを生成する

```
#ifndef TodoApp_Bridging_Header_h
#define TodoApp_Bridging_Header_h

#import <MagicalRecord/MagicalRecord.h>

#endif /* TodoApp_Bridging_Header_h */

//パスの指定を行う。
```

実際に生じたエラーです。
[image: 実際に生じたエラー]